# Search data between dates and name in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a problem where  i need to get the last section through between dates and Name
[image]

i try this formula but it only search for exact date
=LOOKUP(G2,A1:A5,C1:C5)
it gives me a answer of #N/A
and also i dont know how to search it by name

Comment: What would be your answer, `mtce`? Also what is your excel version?

Comment: How do you want them exactly? Do you want to search with name between two date range?

Comment: i have a 2016 ms excel

Comment: i want to get the data mtce or lfex etc.. where it will be search with date within the range and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `Excel-2010` then try below array formula.

```
=INDEX(C1:C5,LARGE(IF((A1:A5>=G2)*(A1:A5<=G3)*(B1:B5=G4),ROW(C1:C5),""),1))
```

Array formula need to put with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

If you have `Excel365` then can try `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A1:A5>=G2)*(A1:A5<=G3)*(B1:B5=G4),C1:C5,,0,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a formula except that ? just asking because it makes my excel laggy

Comment: I am not sure but can you check is `AGGREGATE()` function is available on `EXCEL-2010`. Aggregate function no need array entry.

Comment: does vlookup can be used there?

Comment: May be not. Vlookup can't search data between two date nor from last to first.